# How to display a product from an online shopping website on my website?

Tags: javascript, frontend

I try to write a website. I want to write some details about products which already exist in online shopping websites. When I write these details and my comments on my website, I don't want to share just link. I want to display directly the product which I writing about.

I searched and some people talking about API but I want to do this operation like google map.
like iframe, when user wants to click they will go to the original product page.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to do or what the issue might be.  Show us your code and identify what specifically you are having trouble with.

Comment: You should probably provide the code behind your attempt. The answer is simply to use an iframe as you stated in the question